# flask server unresponsive after second load

Tags: python-3.x, caching, flask, flask-restful

After I implemented caching on my flask server, everything works perfectly on local host. First execution is 8000ms, second is 26ms, therefore its working.

When I deployed the application on the AWS ec2 box, the first execution is 21000ms and whenever I try to run it again, it comes with server not responsive.

This is the code:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask_cache import Cache
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import request
from flask_caching import Cache
import json
import nltk, string
import operator
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import re
import time
import access_json

app = Flask(__name__)

cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

with open('JSON files/thesaurus.json', 'r') as fp:
    thesaurus_dict = json.load(fp)

with open('JSON files/JOBS.json', 'r') as f:
    json_list = json.load(f)

def output(word_list):

    return filter_toplist

@app.route('/postjson', methods=['POST'])
@cache.cached(timeout=20)
def json_handler():
     content = request.get_json(force=True)
     word_list = access_json.read_parsed_JSON(content)
     return jsonify ({'jobs': output(word_list)})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

This is not all of the code but the one relevant to the flask server.

Comment: are there any logs? some output you get when you try to run it again?

Comment: From what I can see @OmerBenHaim the postman console is giving me this: 


`common.js:110732 POST http://52.56.82.57:5000/postjson net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)`

And the Server is just getting a normal post without response:


`88.130.340.99 - - [13/Jan/2019 23:57:04] "POST /postjson HTTP/1.1" 200 -`